# Donut Icing Seems To Deform When I Move One Vertex

Tags: modeling

I was following the Blender donut tutorial by Blender Guru, and on the third part, I try to follow how to model the icing. When I try to move a vertex anywhere, the mesh seems to deform oddly like this:[image: The Donut Icing Is Deformed. There are multiple icing objects at the scene collection because I have tried this many times. I put them somewhere else in the meantime.]

I think I have followed all of the steps, so I don’t know what’s the problem that is causing this. Is there a solution to why the mesh is deformed, and is there a fix for this?

Comment: share your blend file from https://blend-exchange.com/ ,
it would be easier to understand your issue.

Comment: Is it because you have snapping enabled? Try clicking the magnet at the top middle of your viewport.

Comment: The tutorial says to turn snapping on. It worked fine for Blender Guru.